# Best way to activate applications with the end result of some windows being closed?

Tags: applescript, macos-monterey

Trying to automate the process of setting up my MacBook when I turn it on in the morning.

I have to open 7 applications but I don't need all their windows open.

I'd like to run a script that opens these 7 applications but then closes the window of some and leaves the windows of others open.

For example:

I'd like the process to open Google Chrome, Slack & Microsoft Teams all in full screen. However I also need Keeper Password Manager opened but the window closed as I use the shortcut in the top menu bar and not the application window itself. There is also an application called SonicWall Mobile Connect that needs to open but I don't require it's window to be open.

Comment: To open applications without opening its window , use **launch application "appName"** command. To open application with opening window, use **launch** command, then some **delay**, then **activate application "appName"** command. Then, use **try block** with **tell application "System Events" to keystroke "f" using {command down, option down}** when the window 1 became frontmost.

Comment: Just to add, a better way to go fullscreen is to trigger it via the UI button rather than a keystroke, so that you don't need to worry when the app loses focus while the script is running. OP's requirement is almost similar to mine, but instead, I just arrange the windows of the apps I use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
use scripting additions
launch application "AppName"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "AppName"
    set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1 to true
end tell
tell application "AppName" to if it is running then close its front window
```

Since you are working with multiple applications, you should repeat this code for every one, but don't repeat the "use scripting additions" part. If you want to keep an app's window open, then leave out the "tell application "AppName" to if it is running then close its front window" part.
I hope you find this useful!